# ERC1155 - Dynamic URI Not working with overriden uri function

Tags: solidity, remix, nft, erc-1155

I have an erc1155 contract, that should be able to update the metadata dynamically, because i have overriden the uri function like so:

```
 function uri(uint256 packid) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        if(packOpened(packid) == false) {
            return _uri;
        } else {
            return _uriOpened;
        }
 }
```

when i call the uri function from the smart contract itself, it works properly, it gives me the correct metadata url.

However for some reason when i click refresh metadata for the NFT on opensea, or any other website for that matter, the metadata/image isn't updating, and remains the initial metadata.

Does any one know why this could potentially happen?

Any help would be appreciated! thankx

Comment: What does `packOpened(packid)` do? It is possible that some site have cached the previous value.

Comment: It just returns false or true, its just a way to see if that nft has been "Opened" etc, (Internal function)